# calculate frequency of each letter in a string

Tags: c++, string, frequency

I wish to calculate the frequency of each letter in the string.But This is giving me an error.
"String subscript out of range"
Please tell me anyone what is wrong with this code.

```
  string text = "aaabbbbyyuuuuusdddddd" ;  //string of characters
            float arr[256] ,freq[6] ;
            int i=0 ;
            while(i<256)    // initializing a new array of 256 indexes
            {
                arr[i] = 0.00 ;
                i++ ;
            }
            i=0 ;
            int value ;
        // to increament the value within the indexes .index is the ASCII of the character in the string

            while(text[i] != '\0' )    
            {
                value = text[i] ;
                arr[value] = arr[value] + 0.01 ;
                i++ ;
            }
            int j=0 ;
            i=0 ;
            while(i<256)
            {
                if(arr[i] != 0.00)
                {
                    freq[j] = arr[i] ;
                    j++ ;
                }
                i++ ;
            }
            j=0 ;
        //displaying the frequencies of each character 
            while(j<6)
            {
                cout << freq[j] << endl ;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, while `std::string` *is* null-terminated (required in C++11, de facto in most implementations before that), you cannot access past `size()`. If you used `string::at()` directly, then you'd get hit:

> `reference at(size_type pos);`
>        *Throws*: `out_of_range` if `pos >= size()`

which would be true for the null terminator. So the right way to iterate over a `std::string` is either the C++11 way:

```
for (value c : text) { ... }
```

or the C++03 way:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i) {
    value = text[i];
    ...
}
```

You don't need to walk until you hit `'\0`.

The second problem is your terminal loop:

```
j=0 ;
//displaying the frequencies of each character 
while(j<6)
{
    cout << freq[j] << endl ;
}
```

It won't terminate. This is a good reason to prefer to use `for` loops:

```
for (j=0; j < 6; ++j) 
//               ^^^^ you were missing this
{
    cout << freq[j] << endl ;
}
```

Comment: yeah I wasn't incrementing the index in my last loop.

Answer (score 1):

In pre C++11 `std::string`s are not guaranteed to be terminated by `\0` (unlike in the case of C-style `char[]`), thanks to Barry for pointing this out. Use `std::string::size()` to find the size of the string.

Better, try using a `std::map<char, size_t>` for your task

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "aaabbbbyyuuuuusdddddd";
    std::map<char, std::size_t> freq;
    for(auto c: text)
    {
        if( freq.find(c) == freq.end())
            freq[c] = 1; 
        else
            ++freq[c];
    }

    for(auto elem: freq)
    {
        std::cout << elem.first << " -> " << elem.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `std::string::at` to access the elements of the string, like `text.at(i)` instead of `text[i]`, it will test for out of bounds errors, or use a debugger.

Comment: @vsoftco looks like his logic is wrong somewhere , cause after trying both our answers , desired output is wrong.

Comment: In C++11, they are null-terminated - and I think for most implementations even before C++11 they were anyway.

Comment: @Barry, I though `c_str()` gives a zero-terminated string, but not that `std::string` contains internally an additional zero, are you sure about this? Ok, looks like you're right, didn't know that the last character is `charT{}` (21.4.5) :)

Answer (score 0):

Completely redid your code , hope you dont mind , it works now:

```
   char string[100] = "aaabbbbyyuuuuusdddddd";
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
   while ( string[c] != '\0' )
   {

      if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' )
         count[string[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( count[c] != 0 )
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }
```

Comment: But now I am getting problem with the loops :(

Comment: @TaghridMohammad fully edited and tested , it works now

Comment: @TaghridMohammad mark anyone as answer , you will be doing a favour :)